# DAX YTD calculation in a summarize table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate a YTD and LYTD sum in the context of a summarize table.

I am using

```
Units YTD = Calculate(SUM('table'[Units],DATESYTD('Calendar'[Date])))
Units LYTD = Calculate([Units YTD],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))
```

These calculations perform as expected on their own (ie Month and these two calculations) when filtered for Factor 1 and Factor 2.

```
Month  Units YTD | Units LYTD

Jan    1           3

Feb    2           4

Mar    2           5

Apr    4           6

May    6           7
```

The issue is when I place these values in a Summarize function

```
Summary = SUMMARIZE('table',[Factor1],[Factor2],"Units_YTD",[Units YTD],"Units LYTD",[Units LYTD])
```

When running this the YTD number matches up but the LTYD does not. I think that it might be due to my data not having a value on every date, but that does not appear to be an issue for outside the summarize context. In the data table there would be no row for March Current Year (assumed to be zero).

Comment: Not sure your comparison is sound. You should be comparing the results obtained using identical filters: in your first table, these measures are filtered by Month, whereas in your SUMMARIZEd table they are filtered by unique combinations of Factor1 and Factor2.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sorry I left out that I filtered on Factor 1 and Factor 2 on the first table. The issue is that outside the Summarize context; a factor1 and factor 2 table (no month) gives the correct values for Units YTD and Units LYTD